# Add XML Attribute Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am currently using an XSLT to pull values out of an XML document and create a new XML document. Part of my XSLT is below:

```
<xsl:element name="urn:sObjects">
    <xsl:element name="urn1:type">
          <xsl:value-of select="/ProcessData/Create/type"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="CreatedDate">
          <xsl:value-of select="Create/CreatedDate"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Alert_Code__c">
          <xsl:value-of select="Create/AlertCode"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Status__c">
          <xsl:value-of select="Create/Status"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Name">
          <xsl:value-of select="Create/Name"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Order_Id__c">
          <xsl:value-of select="Create/OrderID"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

Currently, this outputs:

```
<urn:sObjects>
  <urn1:type xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">O2C_SAP_Service_Alert__c</urn1:type>
  <CreatedDate />
  <Alert_Code__c>ZD</Alert_Code__c>
  <Status__c>new</Status__c>
  <Name />
  <Order_Id__c>0000000102</Order_Id__c>
</urn:sObjects>
```

What I would like it to output is:

```
<urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:O2C_Alert__c">
  <urn1:type xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">O2C_SAP_Service_Alert__c</urn1:type>
  <CreatedDate />
  <Alert_Code__c>ZD</Alert_Code__c>
  <Status__c>new</Status__c>
  <Name />
  <Order_Id__c>0000000102</Order_Id__c>
</urn:sObjects>
```

In other words, I would like to add the attribute `xsi:type="urn1:O2C_Alert__c"` to this XML message.

How could I do that, using the XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needn't use `xsl:element` to create an element.
You can simplify it to the following (make sure that there is a namespace declared for `xsi` prefix):

```
<urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:O2C_Alert__c">
    <urn1:type>
        <xsl:value-of select="/ProcessData/Create/type"/>
    </urn1:type>
</urn:sObjects>
```

**EDIT:**
To make the attribute value dynamic, you can use `{}` to evaluate an xpath as following:

```
<urn:sObjects xsi:type="{a/b/c}">
```

Or, you can use:

```
<urn:sObjects>
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">
        <xsl:value-of select="a/b/c"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <!-- followed by other attributes, and then by elements -->
</urn:sObjects>
```

Make sure that all `xsl:attribute` are declared before any child elements.

Comment: Great! That worked. Thanks a lot. Now, let's say I want to make that xsi:type field dynamic? How could I do that?